# Latest changes in google.com/recaptcha/api.js not Supported for Edge browser IE Mode

Tags: recaptcha

We had successfully added Goggle Recaptcha to login page of our portal. As our application used some features specific to Internet Explorer, therefore users accessed the application with the Edge browser in IE mode. This worked absolutely fine over the years, however in the last few weeks we observed that Google Recaptcha was not loading when the application was accessed with the Edge browser in IE (Internet explorer 11) mode.

On further investigation, it was observed that loading of api.js via

```html
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' async defer></script>
```

gives the following error:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'prepend'

Please suggest how to overcome the problem.

Comment: If you haven't written any code on your own, please contact Google's developer support. But keep in mind that IE 11 is pretty outdated and shouldn't be used since years

Comment: How to contact/connect with Google's developer Support

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer does not meet the [browser requirements of reCAPTCHA](https://support.google.com/recaptcha/faq/6080947#6223828)

- desktop (Windows, Linux, Mac)

  - Chrome
  - Firefox
  - Safari
  - Chromium Edge
- mobile

  - Chrome
  - Safari
  - Android native browser

Running Edge in IE mode also fails to meet this browser requirement.